# Saving xml Document into DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Ive got an asp.net page in which im using c# to read an xml document and add each entry into a listview.

I then have the function for the user to add a new entry to the list view but i cant figure out how to save it on a button event.

This is what I have to load the document.

```
protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        using (DataTable tabListView1 = new DataTable())
        {
            tabListView1.Columns.Add("value", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            xmlDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/XmlFile/ListView1.xml");
            XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("root/data[@open='1']");
            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeList)
            {
                DataRow dr = tabListView1.NewRow();
                dr["value"] = xmlNode.InnerText;
                tabListView1.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            ListView1.DataSource = tabListView1;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
        TextBox3.Text = "Microsoft";

    }
```

How can i make it save changes back to ListView1.xml? Thanks!

Comment: can you post an example of the xml output that you want? It would be useful to explain the significance of the @open attribute for example.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<root> <data open="1">Microsoft Excel 2010</data> <data open="1">Microsoft Powerpoint 2010</data> <data open="1">Microsoft Outlook 2010</data>  </root>

Comment: so a user can add a new software entry and then save it to that list is what im after. I can add to the list just not save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can get your datasource back as a DataTable from the control you are managing it with, this should help.

`private static void SaveXml(string pathAndFileName, DataTable source)

      {

         XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

         var root = xmlDoc.CreateElement("root");

         xmlDoc.AppendChild(root);`

```
     foreach (DataRow row in source.Rows)  
     {
        var dataElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("data");
        var openAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("open");
        openAttribute.Value = "1";
        dataElement.Attributes.Append(openAttribute);
        dataElement.InnerText = row["value"].ToString();
        root.AppendChild(dataElement);
     }
     xmlDoc.Save(pathAndFileName);
  }
```